# Android - null pointer exception when nothing is typed in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext where I enter the quantity of products.Clearing all data in edit box of quantity,causes device to crash.I used**addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()**

[image]

**Code**

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s1=pricetxt.getText().toString();
        String s2=edittext.getText().toString();
        SQLiteDatabase mydb=cntxt.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO add2cart (pqty)VALUES('"+s2+"')");
        int i1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
        int i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
        int res=i1*i2;
        totltxt.setText(Integer.toString(res));

        if (s2.matches("")) {

            edittext.setText("");

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    }



    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: Obviously on text change can give you null strings, what if the user types something, and press backspace! Handle the conditions, also your code doesn't tell where you are getting null pointer exception!

Comment: handle null pointer exceptions when nothing is typed, imagine the scenario when your edittext is empty, then you will get NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this crash because s1 or s2 might be empty or null so you have to check for the empty or null string.

change your code to this:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String s1 = pricetxt.getText().toString();
                String s2 = edittext.getText().toString();
                SQLiteDatabase mydb = cntxt.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO add2cart (pqty)VALUES('" + s2 + "')");
                int i1 = 0;
                if (!s1.equals("")) {
                    i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                }
                int i2 = 0;
                if (!s2.equals("")) {
                    i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
                }
                int res = i1 * i2;
                totltxt.setText(Integer.toString(res));

                if (s2.matches("")) {

                    edittext.setText("");

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

The error clearly says here

```
 int i1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
 int i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
```

that mean you parse empty string value of `s1` , `s2` to `int`. So before parse to it just check

```
 if(!s1.equals("")) {
     int i1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
 }

 if(!s2.equals("")) {
     int i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are doing it wrong

you getvalue of edittext from CharSequence s when using textchange listener

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String s1 = pricetxt.getText().toString();
                String s2 = s.toString();
                SQLiteDatabase mydb=cntxt.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO add2cart (pqty)VALUES('"+s2+"')");
                int i1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
                int i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);
                int res=i1*i2;
                totltxt.setText(Integer.toString(res));

                if (s.equals("")||s==null) {
                    edittext.setText("");
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```